# Find hashed data SQL

Tags: php

Happy Saturday! I am creating a software where the user shall be assigned a key, which will then be hashed by "PASSWORD_DEFAULT" in PHP and posted to a database. The user should in another file then be able to write in the assigned key, which will be controlled by the **hashed** database. The problem with password_hash/_verify is that it is purposefully expensive: if it will be called more than a handful of times, the script will be slow. Assuming the database will be big it won't work since it will lead to timeout errors.

What options are there to this? I post the current (wrong) code in case somebody does not understand what I mean.

```
<?php
require_once('dbh.php');
$sql = 'SELECT * from license';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $hash = password_verify($_POST['key'], $row['user_key']);
}

if ($hash) {
    echo "Found!";
} else {
    echo "Nothing found!";
}
```

Comment: Why are you using password hash for just a simple key. Since it's not a password

Comment: I fail to see how the database size is any related to password_verify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `password_hash` for passwords and *only* passwords. The security that Bcrypt provides depends on this operation being necessarily slow, so you should do as few tests as possible. Most identity management systems require another factor like a username or email before accepting a password so as to test against one record, or worst case, all accounts that email has registered.

Testing against every single record in the database is completely impractical. This could take minutes, even hours, per request. This is good if you're trying to harden against password cracking attacks, it severely impairs anyone trying to crack your database, but it's not good if that's your login strategy.

API keys can't really be encrypted or hashed because they're used as a lookup key. Store them as plain text. If your application gets compromised you're in a bad spot, but at least you can invalidate these keys and generate new ones. The problem with plain-text or easily cracked passwords is that people *re-use* passwords across multiple sites. This is not true for API keys.